# Kotlin - Sort maps collection

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin

I have a function

```
fun init(properties: Collection<Map<Any, Any>>?) {
    properties?.filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
}
```

1. I need to filter out empty maps.
2. I only need maps which have keys and values of type `String`.
3. For the remaining maps, I want to iterate the keys to get the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.all { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html) to check that all [`.keys`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/keys.html) and [`.values`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/values.html) are Strings:

```
properties
    ?.filter { 
        it.isNotEmpty() && 
        it.keys.all { key -> key is String } && 
        it.values.all { value -> value is String }
    }
    ?.forEach { /* do some stuff with it */ }
```

Note that you will still need an unchecked cast to operate on the filtered maps as `Map<String, String>`, because the compiler cannot infer the type from the keys and values check.

Comment: Thank man. This code give me filtered collection of map. But how i can use forEach - for all Maps. I mean forEach key in each map get value ?

Comment: You would need to `flatMap`the properties. So building on hotkey's answer it would look something like this:
`properties
    ?.filter { 
        it.isNotEmpty() && 
        it.keys.all { key -> key is String } && 
        it.values.all { value -> value is String }
    }
?.flatMap { it.entries }
?.forEach { /* do something */ }`